# Serial communication from Raspberry to Arduino with phpSerial not working

Tags: php, c++, arduino, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I develop a software and I need to use the serial port of the raspberry to send data to arduino.

I use phpSerial but It's impossible to know what data are received on Arduino with this code. I test with led on the port 2 but when I send this data the led does not light..

**ON RASPBERRY**

```
    $serial = new phpSerial;
    $serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
    $serial->confBaudRate(115200);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);
    $serial->deviceOpen();
    sleep(1);
    $serial->sendMessage("1");
    echo $serial->readPort();
    $serial->deviceClose();
```

**ON ARDUINO**

```
  if (Serial.available() > 0)  {

      readed_char[i] = (char)Serial.read();
      Serial.print(readed_char[i]);

      if (readed_char[0] == '1'){

         digitalWrite(2,HIGH);


       }
    }
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you opened the serial on the same baud rate?

Comment: Yes on 115200 bauds.. I've found this tutorial : https://peopleorientedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/raspberry-pi-arduino-and-php-a-home-automation-baby-step/

But not working :/

Comment: Have you configured pin 2 as output on Arduino? Try to change its state whatever character arrives (so don't check if char == '1')

Comment: It's ok, I've found the solution in this tutorial Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to configure hardware handshake?

You read into readed_char[i] but check readed_char[0], is this correct?

BTW: there is no "readed" in English.

Comment: Oups lol, I've found.. On the tutorial : https://peopleorientedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2013/05/12/raspberry-pi-arduino-and-php-a-home-automation-baby-step/

In the troubleshooting section, I opened minicom and I changed the name of the port for 'ACM0'.. 

In the php_serial_class.php :

change : $ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " " . (int) $rate, $out);

to 

$ret = $this->_exec("stty -F " . $this->_device . " raw speed " . (int) $rate, $out);